# How do I use vault items in templates?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm learning chef.

I have this recipe:

```
chef_gem 'chef-vault' do
  compile_time true if respond_to?(:compile_time)
end

require 'chef-vault'

vault = ChefVault::Item.load("vault01", "vaultitem1")

log 'DEBUG' do
  message vault['myuser']
  level :info
end

directory 'c:/blah'

template 'c:/blah/template.txt' do
  source 'template.txt.erb'
end
```

You can see I'm getting the value out of the vault in the recipe.

How should I insert these values into my template file?

Is there a way I can get the vault vaules from inside of my template.txt.erb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `variables` property. You pass it a hash and then those keys are available as variables in your template:

```
template 'c:/blah/template.txt' do
  source 'template.txt.erb'
  variables vault: ChefVault::Item.load("vault01", "vaultitem1")
end

# and then in the template
<%= @vault['foo'] %>
```

Also check out the chef-vault cookbook (distinct from the chef-vault gem) which has a nice `chef_vault_item()` helper to make testing easier.

Comment: Ah great I wasn't sure if I needed to call the vault methods in side of the template itself or inject it. I was going to look at the cookbook next, but still unsure what advantages it offers over the gem

Comment: Mostly just that helper, and it's got a recipe you can include instead of the `chef_gem` snippet you have there. It's pretty minimal :)